# How to debug attributes in model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm getting `undefined method email .... app/models/user.rb:110:in 'collect'`.

How do I log what each attribute is? I am trying to debug to see what the issue is.

`user.rb`:

```
  def self.substitutions(users)
    users = [users] unless users.is_a?(Array)
    substitutions = {}
    %w(email full_name owner_name profile_url business_name perishable_token).each {|attribute| substitutions["[#{attribute}]"] = users.collect(&attribute.to_sym)}
    substitutions
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return a hash of the all the attributes and their values for an instance of User:

```
user.attributes
```

Comment: so in the case of my code should it be something like `logger.debug "Attr: #{users.attributes}` I'm lost whether is should be users or user??

Comment: Has to be run on `user` (singular).  You could just fire up the Rails console and run something like `User.first.attributes` assuming you have some data available.